# SQL Server 2012 replication strategy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got SQL2012 running on 2 different servers with public, static IP addresses. I want to implement replication in a way that will keep both servers in sync at all times, regardless of which server is actually receiving the data. I've been reading about the subscriber/publisher model but I'm not exactly sure which should be which. A few facts about our setup:

- I'm trying to achieve failover. If server A goes down, I need server B to be operational and have all latest data, or as close as possible. And vice versa. When the server comes back online, I need the replication to get caught up quickly and start working again. I need failures to be graceful, in other words I can't have server A get weird just because server B went offline.
- I don't need realtime replication, but close would be nice. If server A was 10 seconds behind server B with data updates, nobody would care. But if it were an hour behind, that would be bad. Fast DB performance is more important that realtime replication, but again, close would be nice.
- My database is just shy of 900Mb, and grows by 3Mb per day.

I am looking for advice on the best way to set this up given my setup and needs. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one server will be Primary and the other Failover, use [Log Shipping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx). It will keep two databases the same for all transactions completed on Primary server upto the failure moment. All transactions that have not completed at the moment of failure, will not appear on Failover server, so they should resubmitted by the application and hit Failover server.

Also there should be a Recovery procedure, to ensure than Primary server is up to date.

Useful articles:

[Database Mirroring and Log Shipping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187016.aspx).

[Configure Log Shipping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190640.aspx)

Comment: Stoleg, this sounds good, but what happens if Primary fails and Secondary gets used for 1 day, then Primary comes back up and needs to get sync'ed up, and receive all latest data changes on Secondary. How does that happen?

Comment: After researching some more it seems Database Mirroring might be the best option. Any reason to use Log Shipping when I only have 2 servers?

Comment: Recovery is a necessary part of Failover process. As you have not specified the sync back logic/requirements, I've suggested a simple way of keeping second server up to date. There are several ways of achiving Failover functionality and it depends on business use of the system.